# What are options to deploy and manage wcf applications centralized way?

Tags: wcf, deployment

What are options to manage centralized way many wcf applicaitons on many servers (hosted in IIS6, IIS7, self-hosted)  Something like a tool or framework using which it is possible to deploy, update and change config sections remotely? What is wrong in this arhcetecture (something should be wrong since it is not easy to find any information).

Answer (score 1):

We use powershell remoting in powershell 2.0 (using invoke-command to run PS commands across a remoting session.) It works for us.